# Code to cycle through and save pivot table fields stopped working...any ideas?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cycle through items in pivot table field and save the pdf of the page for each.  I had this set up and working but a was tweaking it and now it is throwing an error when it hits `pf.CurrentPAge = pi.Value`.  I'm pulling my hair out as I can't figure out what changed to suddenly make it stop working (in the course of an hour!).  Any one have any ideas?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim pt As PivotTable, pi As PivotItem, pf As PivotField
    Dim lLoop As Long
    Dim strExportPath As String

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("AU & Name")

    strExportPath = "C:\Users\nbelair\desktop"

    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pf.CurrentPage = pi.Value
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strExportPath 
    & "\" & "test.pdf"
    Next pi

End Sub
```

Comment: What error is it?

Comment: It is "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: Are the values of `pi` and `pf` valid at that time? (Use `Debug.Print pf.Name` and `Debug.Print pi.Name` within the for loop, but before the problem line. The names will be printed to the "Immediate" window in the code view.)

Comment: Well I did that and now I am more confused.  The name printed for pf returns the name of the field ("AU & Name") I want but pi returns a wrong name, that is it returns an old filter value, one I changed.  Any idea why the pi value is pulling an old one and not a new one?  Of course I am thinking that is the issue and it may not be...

Comment: I figured it out and it wasn't VBA related, it was due to the pivot table holding on to old field values which of course it couldn't find when asked to be the code.  So after a little research I went into the pivot tabel options and under data changed the setting for the fields it retains to none and now it works!!!  Thank you for your patience and help all!